# Setting up Subversion on a Red Hat system

Tags: php, svn, redhat

I'm fairly new to the world of versioning but would like to introduce Subversion into our small development team as we're finding that more and more we are working on the same projects/files. We primarily code in `PHP` on a `LAMP` environment (Red Hat Enterprise).

What I'm looking for are some starting points to get me up and running such as installation/configuration guides for Red Hat. I use Dreamweaver `CS3` (I see that Subversion functions will be introduced in `CS4`) so would be willing to look at other PHP IDEs with Subversion integration, do you have any preferences? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what version of RHEL you are running.  Setting up Subversion in general is very easy you just have to install the binaries and run svnserve or adapt the Apache configuration.

1. Get it: http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html
2. Install it
3. `svnadmin create --fs-type=fsfs`

After that you have a repository which you can serve via apache or svnserve.  I can recommend Apache because it scales better, is easier to maintain and allows you to access the repository via DAV.

Example configurations are here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html

Answer (score 1):

Installing subversion is likely not going to be the hardest part, what's going to be the difficult part is how you access the repository. There's a variety of options (file share on the network, subversion over SSH, through an http connection). Each has their own pro's and con's. How are you currently developing? If you are all using the same webroot for instance, version control is not going to help, as you'd still be changing each others files, so you'll have to create separate sites for each developer.

As for the IDE, there's a great shell integration for Windows in the form of [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), which would still allow you to work with your favourite tools and still have easy access to the SVN features.

Answer (score 1):

On a RHEL system, the easiest way to install subversion is by using yum:

yum install subversion

Answer (score 0):

These are good for Linux + Subversion:
http://articles.slicehost.com/subversion
Plus it goes into multiple repositories, WebDAV and a lot of other things. Useful for Windows devs too as most of the info can be used in Windows too.