# SVN on webhosting

Tags: svn

I have been getting into SVN quite recently. I decided that I wanted to install the SVN server on my web hosting space. My host is godaddy. So here's my question:
How can I install SVN on godaddy. I can SSH into the server, and the server is running Red Hat 4. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would contact godaddy to see if they support this.  It really is up to the web host to support an application like this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used GoDaddy for this.  However, you should be able to install it using yum or the binaries at http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/redhat.html .  See also [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114555/setting-up-subversion-on-a-red-hat-system).

Once you have it installed, you can set up the server to [talk svn+ssh](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html)

EDIT: Do you have root access at all (e.g. su)?  If so, try the collab packages I linked.  If not, you may need to consult with GoDaddy.

Comment: small problem, i can't use their digital key or whatever. The sudo command doesn't work so I can't get admin access. Also, yum is not supported.

Comment: I would highly recommend against using applications outside of the Linux repositories. At my last job, we modified a version of mediawiki for a specific purpose, and it hasn't been upgraded for years.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of web hosting.  If all you have is virtual HTTP hosting, you might be able to get away with downloading it to an SSH shell, building it, then installing it to your local directory.  Then you can get something like the viewsvn CGI engine, and point it to your custom-built subversion executables.

I had to do this recently with git and gitweb on 1and1.com.  It's definitely possible.  Maybe not as flexible as having your own server, and you may not be able to get Subversion DAVFS working (which is a crying shame).

Comment: I can't compile anything, godaddy doesn't support gcc

Answer (score 0):

On redhat ES4, if you have root access, ssh into the server and run "yum install svn". That should fetch and install all packages and needed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For those who looking to set up a SVN repository and then access using `SSH`, here is a great tutorial for that. Even though, this article is not from GoDaddy, the setup can't be that hugely different.

- Create repository / connect to repository : https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/version-control-systems1/configuring-subversion
- Generate SSH keys for authentication : https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/getting-started-guide/accessing-your-account/using-ssh-keys

**Create the repository,**

```
svnadmin create /home/USERNAME/REPOSITORY
```

**SSH into the repository using a tool, like [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)**

```
svn co svn+hosting://USERNAME@example.com/home/USERNAME/REPOSITORY
```